# Send file upload data from AngularJS to C# backend

Tags: c#, angularjs

I'm trying to upload a file and want to send upload file data to the C# back-end. Having this code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="file" id="upload" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().uploadedFile(this)" multiple />
```

**AngularJS Serivce**

```
uploadfile: function (files, type, status) {
    var route = 'api/sc/ir/cid/' + $cookies.get("cid") + '/type/' + type + '/status/' + status;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      $http.post(serviceBase + route, files[i], {
        withCredentials: false,
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      })
    }
    return true;
  }
```

**C# Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/sc/ir/cid/{cid:int}/type/{type}/status/{status}")]
    [ResponseType(typeof(ValidateModel))]
    public IHttpActionResult AddFileRequests(int cid, string type, string status, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        var newRequest = logic.UploadDocument(clinicId, type, status, file);
        return Created(Request.RequestUri.ToString(), newRequest);
    }
```

The problem is that the 'file' object is null when getting to back-end, but it's nicely populated in front-end. What am I missing?

Comment: Try `Content-Type` equals to `multipart/form-data` instead of `application/json`?

Comment: Already done that :(

Comment: Hey, Did you get answer to this question? I've a same problem.